# TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not list - pygame.transform.flip()

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror, pygame-surface

I'm working on movement animations and using pygame.transform.flip to make the character run backward if some condition happens.
the problem is that the pygame.transform.flip() method is accepting pygame.Surface type only and that a problem because my animation running trough a list

```
self.run_scaled = [pygame.transform.scale(self.animation_run[i], (self.width, self.height)) for i in
                           range(len(self.animation_run))]

        for i in range(len(self.animation_run)):
            WIN.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.run_scaled, True, False), (x, y))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get an item form the list:

<s>`WIN.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.run_scaled, True, False), (x, y))`</s>

```py
WIN.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.run_scaled[i], True, False), (x, y))
```